# sample rate of ADC with raspberry pi and arduino

Tags: pi-3, arduino

I connected the ADC `PCF8591` to the `raspberry pi3` and the number of samples per second is about 80.
When I connect this ADC to `Arduino`, the number of sampls per second with baud rate 9600, about 270 samples per second , and when I set baud rate on 250k, it will be 500 samples per second.
with this tutorial I started with ADC 
https://www.sunfounder.com/learn/sensor-kit-v2-0-for-raspberry-pi-b-plus/lesson-13-pcf8591-sensor-kit-v2-0-for-b-plus.html
 I2C clock of ADC is 100K.
why with the `raspberry pi` cannot get higher samples rate like `arduino`?
What can you do to increase the number of Samples and how much can it be?

Comment: Which example were you using from the site, the python or the C example. The C example has a delay of 10ms so you won't exceed 100Hz theoretically. You can try to reduce that but errors might start coming in. You can follow [this](http://www.mindsensors.com/blog/how-to/change-i2c-speed-with-raspberry-pi) tutorial to increase the I2C speed

Comment: @karan   I use C example and I comment the delay of 10 ms but my sample rate is low still, the PCF8591 maximum SCL is 100k and when change the baud rate in raspberry ,ADC doesn't work correctly

Comment: How much did you increase the baud rate too. Anything over 400Khz might be unstable. Did you try increasing the baud rate in steps to see if that helped

Comment: yes I change the baud rate of raspberry pi to 400k,1m,...,and I get only 255 from ADC

Comment: its really hard to say how much can it increase without looking at the underlying code and checking the datasheet. There might be delays in the software implementation or it might not be doing it well. If you have a logic analyzer around you should be able to spot where the delay is coming from otherwise it might be hard to debug it.